# Are there any differences / limitations with Stored Procedures when using a SQL Azure Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

Can someone tell me if there are any limitations when it comes to creating Stored Procedures of Functions on a Microsoft SQL Azure database. I know there are differences between this and the normal SQL Server 2012 but I have not been able to find anything that shows the differences as they relate to Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to msdn, there's no specific limitation on stored procedures by themselves.
However you can not use all the features of on premise sql server (nowadays User Defined DataType (UDT) for instance ...)

Here's the informations we find on MSDN :

- [SQL Server Feature Limitations (Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394115.aspx)
- Moreover theres is also some limitations on Transact-SQL Support.
  Here is the [Azure SQL Database Transact-SQL Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336250.aspx)

The following links **used to list** the support of the various statements

- [Unsupported Transact-SQL Statements (Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee336253.aspx)
- [Partially Supported Transact-SQL Statements (Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee336267.aspx)
- [Supported Transact-SQL Statements (Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee336270.aspx)

Since **SQL Server 2014** these topics  been flagged has obsolete and the documentation has been updated and we can read on [SQL Server Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dn198336.aspx)

> The Transact-SQL topics in this SQL Server Language Reference node
>   have been modified to include the following information. The versions
>   of SQL Server (starting with SQL Server 2008) that apply to each
>   topic. The Microsoft platforms (SQL Server and Windows Azure SQL
>   Database) that apply to each topic.

From now on the [Transact-SQL Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx) for each topic we find a mention like :

[image]